# How to fix sql joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, ssms, inner-join

Having trouble properly writing sql joins. I am joining three tables to determine a count.

**Table 1 - EmmaResponseOpens**

```
[storecode]
[firstname]
[lastname] 
[px_or_ot_joindate] 
[datelastdined] 
[pxcardnumber] 
[birthdate] 
[fishbowl_join_date] 
[ot_signup] 
[last_input_source] 
[timestamp] 
[member_id] 
[member_since] 
[email_domain] 
[email_user] 
[email] 
[member_status_id] 
[mailing_id]
```

**Table 2 -  EmmaCustomer**

```
[Status] 
[Confirmed_Opt_In] 
[Account_ID] 
[StoreCode] 
[FirstName] 
[LastName] 
[Eclub_Member] 
[Email_Number] 
[Eclub] 
[Last_Input_Source] 
[Fishbowl_Join_Date] 
[Px_Or_Ot_Joindate] 
[Ot_Signup] 
[Member_ID] 
[Last_Modified_At] 
[Member_Status_ID] 
[Plaintext_Preferred] 
[Email_Error] 
[Member_Since] 
[Bounce_Count] 
[Deleted_At] 
[Email] 
[pxCardNumber]
[Member_Group_ID] 
[Preferred_Location_Henrys] 
[Preferred_Location_Palomino] 
[Preferred_Location_Kincaids] 
[Preferred_Location_Psc] 
[Preferred_Location_Stanfords] 
[portland_or] 
[bellevue_wa] 
[plano_tx] 
[denver_co] 
[pdx_airport_or] 
[seattle_wa] 
[st_paul] 
[oakland] 
[bloomington] 
[redondo_beach] 
[burlingame] 
[bellevue] 
[seattle] 
[los_angeles] 
[indianapolis] 
[san_francisco]    
[tigard] 
[portland_washington]
[walnut_creek] 
[portland_066] 
[portland_082] 
[hillsboro] 
[lake_oswego] 
[clackamas] 
[tukwila]
```

**Table 3 - EmmaGroups**

```
[active_count] 
[deleted_at] 
[error_count] 
[optout_count] 
[group_type] 
[member_group_id] 
[purged_at] 
[account_id] 
[group_name] 
[date_time]
```

Query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Email)
FROM MyEmma.dbo.EmmaResponseOpens t1 
INNER JOIN EmmaCustomer t2 
ON t1.member_id = t2.member_id
INNER JOIN Groups t3
ON t3.member_group_id = t2.member_group_id
```

I am expecting what doesn't match in `EmmaResponseOpens` and `EmmaCustomers` to be returned (using `member_id`) and then filtered based on `member_group_id`.

Comment: What doesn't match? An inner join explicitly finds matches. My understanding from what you've written is that you want to find EmmaCustomer's that do not have an EmmaResponseOpens row, and then join those selected EmmaCustomer's to Groups and count...well you're trying to count Email from EmmaResponseOpens, so that doesn't make sense. 
What exactly are you trying to achieve? You want to find EmmaResponseOpens that don't have matching EmmaCustomers? Where does Groups fit in?

Comment: To also return records that that don't match, use an outer join. But if it doesn't match then `member_group_id` will be NULL so you'll filter it out anyway

Comment: To be more explicit: I need to get a count of Email based on criteria in a group. Members are filtered on 'has not opened any mailing' (determining if they are in EmmaResponseOpens), 'exists in member group id 1' (uses id# specific to our company), 'does not exist in member group id 2' (uses specific id#).

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. You are neither explaining nor illustrating what you want a query to return or even what you think join does. PS What does "what doesn't match in EmmaResponseOpens and EmmaCustomers to be returned" mean? Find out what inner join on returns: first it does a cross join it then keeps only rows satisfying the on. Please clarify via post edits, not comments. PS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Email)
FROM MyEmma.dbo.EmmaResponseOpens t1 
RIGHT JOIN EmmaCustomer t2 
ON t1.member_id = t2.member_id
INNER JOIN Groups t3
ON t3.member_group_id = t2.member_group_id
WHERE t1.member_id IS NULL
```